# Multiple user stream 1 video (Bandwidth calculation)

Tags: video, webserver, bandwidth, video-streaming

I have upload `.mp4` file on my server. The video file size is 58 MB. I have some question:

- If 10 users stream this video at the same time then how much bandwidth they are used?
- If video consuming too much bandwidth then what is alternative way?

I have not too much bandwidth.

Comment: By bandwidth, do you mean data per time (as in, say, MBit/s) or overall traffic volume used after everyone finished watching the video?

Comment: @DanielB yes. data per time and overall traffic volume used on my site